# Service gnocchi-api not found

Tags: service, openstack, ceilometer

I've been installing Ceilometer for Openstack Pike on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using [this install guide](https://docs.openstack.org/ceilometer/pike/install/install-base-ubuntu.html).

Everything went ok, up to the moment, when  but when I've tried to restart `gnocchi-api` I got message

> Failed to start gnocchi-api.service: Unit gnocchi-api.service not found.

I checked `/etc/init.d` and there is no script `gnocchi-api` (although `gnocchi-metricd` is, and it's working properly). Tried reinstalling package `gnocchi-api`, but it didn't help. When starting `gnocchi-api` normally, from the command line it works, although sends a bunch of warnings ([but I think they are common](https://bugs.launchpad.net/keystonemiddleware/+bug/1722444))

I'm looking for a way to make it work normally - like a service and using conf file.

> 2017-11-27 20:01:40.593 6059 INFO gnocchi.rest.app [-] WSGI config used: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gnocchi/rest/api-paste.ini
>
> 2017-11-27 20:01:40.753 6059 WARNING keystonemiddleware._common.config [-] The option `"__file__"` in conf is not known to auth_token
>
> 2017-11-27 20:01:40.759 6059 WARNING keystonemiddleware._common.config [-] The option "configkey" in conf is not known to auth_token
>
> 2017-11-27 20:01:40.760 6059 WARNING keystonemiddleware._common.config [-] The option "here" in conf is not known to auth_token
>
> 2017-11-27 20:01:40.762 6059 WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] AuthToken middleware is set with keystone_authtoken.service_token_roles_required set to False. This is backwards compatible but deprecated behaviour. Please set this to True.
>
> 2017-11-27 20:01:40.768 6059 WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Configuring auth_uri to point to the public identity endpoint is required; clients may not be able to authenticate against an admin endpoint
>
> STARTING test server gnocchi.rest.app.build_wsgi_app
> Available at http://127.0.1.1:8000/
> DANGER! For testing only, do not use in production

Answer (score 0):

apt-get currently pulls version 3.1.9 of gnocchi-api. If you manually install gnocchi-api 3.1.2, this service file is very much there in it. 
service gnocchi-api start works fine with this.

But I am not sure if functionality is ok or if this is an intended change with 3.1.9.. Still to check these.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same on the latest version on Ubuntu 16.04 / gnocchi version 4.2.0

Confirmed bug as of now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ceilometer/+bug/1750933

gnocchi-api.service unit cannot be started as it has not been created.